# Relation between Hamiltonian and Eulers paths

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have a follow up question on the problem discussed here:
[A $3 \times 3 \times 3$ cube has no Hamiltonian path starting at the corner.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102734/a-3-times-3-times-3-cube-has-no-hamiltonian-path-starting-at-the-corner)

[Graph theory 27 cube cheese and mouse problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1779243/graph-theory-27-cube-cheese-and-mouse-problem)

Can the question be reformuled in terms of Euler path (the worm must use every edge exactly once)?

Comment: What do you mean by "Can the question be reformuled"?

Comment: They solve the problem by saying there is no Hamiltonian path. Can one not say that "since there is no Eulerian path, there is no solution"?

Comment: The existence of Eulerian paths and the existence of Hamiltonian paths have no relation to each other. You can see whether a Eulerian path exists in a graph just by looking at the degrees of the vertices. Finding out whether a Hamiltonian path exists is generally a very hard problem (it is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem)).

Comment: But can you solve that exercise by saying that there is no eulerian path, instead of saying there is no hamiltonian path? Thank you.

Comment: No. That exercise is about Hamiltonian paths, and giving an answer about Eulerian paths is a non-sequitur, a totally unrelated subject.

Comment: Why not? Can you not say that the mouse cannot take an Eulerian path to the center?

Comment: An Eulerian path uses every edge exactly once, but will visit vertices that have degree greater than $2$ several times. In a Hamiltonian path you are not allowed to revisit vertices, as they all have to be visited exactly once.

Comment: Simple example of a graph that has a Hamiltonian path but no Eulerian path: $K_4$, the complete graph of 4 vertices, which you can also think of as the edges of a tetrahedron. Hamiltonian path is easy, but it has 4 vertices with odd degree so has no Eulerian path.

Comment: But even if you are authorized to revisit vertices in an Eulerian path, if the edges have been consummed, you should not be able to gain access to the cube you are trying to visit.

Comment: An Eulerian path has to consume all the edges. A Hamiltonian path does not. If an Eulerian path is not possible because it is not possible to consume all the edges, that says nothing at all about whether a Hamiltonian path is possible. On the $K_4$ graph, an Eulerian path would need 6 steps because there are 6 edges (which is not possible on this graph). A Hamiltonian path on $K_4$ has just 3 steps, since there are only 4 vertices. They are completely different things.

Comment: But yet, if there is no eulerian path than the mouse cannot eat the cheese in the middle. Can't we use that as a justification?

Comment: They are unrelated things. What else can I say?

Comment: Thank you for your patience Jaap, I understand they are unrelated. I just wonder if you cannot use the second argument anyway because the consequence is the same?

Comment: The 3x3x3 cube does not have a Hampath that ends in the centre, but it does have other Hampaths that end for example at another corner, so the mouse can eat the centre but just not at the end. There are graphs with Hampaths and no Euler paths like this one, there are graphs with Euler paths but no Hampaths, there are graphs with both, there are graphs with neither. Euler paths are always different paths to Hampaths except in graphs with no branches (all vertices of degree 2 or less) because then there only one possible path. How is the consequence the same when the paths always differ?

Comment: I get what you are saying I think. It is my first week studying graph theory. How do I distinguish when a question is on Euler or Hamiltonian path?

Comment: Look at their definitions. Use all edges exactly once = Euler; use all vertices exactly once = Hamilton.